# How to generate pdf in urdu language in android

Tags: android, fonts, itext, urdu

Can anyone tell me how I generate pdf reports in urdu or any other language except english ? I want just headings (hardcoded) in urdu language. All other fields are in english. So how can I write my headings in Urdu language? All I am trying is not working. The pdf is created but urdu is not shown. Here is my code :

```
private void savePDF(){
    Document mDoc = new Document();
    fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis());
    filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Cattle App/" ;
    try{
        File dir = new File(filePath);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

        file = new File(dir, selName + "_" +fileName+".pdf");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(mDoc,fOut);
        mDoc.open();

        mDoc.addTitle("Cattle App");
        mDoc.addSubject("Add Buyer and sellers");
        mDoc.addKeywords("Cattle App");
        mDoc.addAuthor("Softix");
        mDoc.addCreator("Fahad");

        Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
        Paragraph repTitle = new Paragraph("الیکٹرونک ریکارڈ مینیجمنٹ سسٹم", catFont);
        repTitle.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        preface.add(repTitle);

        Paragraph repTitlepowered = new Paragraph("رسید براے ٹیکس فری کیٹل مارکیٹ____________________________", smallBold);
        repTitlepowered.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        preface.add(repTitlepowered);
        Paragraph emptyL = new Paragraph("\n");
        preface.add(emptyL);
        mDoc.add(preface);

        mDoc.close();

    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: see this - the font encoding section: https://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=171&t=How_To_Write_Non-English_Text_To_PDF_Using_Java

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is simple.try giving font to the file like:-

1)you did not specify a PdfFont when creating the Paragraph object. As a result the default PdfFont will be chosen (Helvetica, regular, 12).

2)Helvetica does not contain the glyphs needed to render all possible scripts you listed. When iText asks the PdfFont "please give me the glyph for character x" and the PdfFont returns null, iText simply does not draw anything. That's why it comes out as blank.

3)Some advanced typographic features (ligatures among others) are only available using pdfCalligraph (a closed source addon for iText7). You need these features to accurately represent Hindi, Tamil (and various other non-western scripts)